# Install SDK for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, windows, sdk

I am trying to install Java SDK for windows 7 (Ultimate version, 64bit), I downloaded the following file from oracle website: jdk-7u9-windowsx64.exe. When I try to execute it, I get an error that it is not a valid win 32 application. I think the JDK version is correct. Can somebody help me out? Also, comment if you need more info about my machine configuration to help me out.

Edit: I have 4 GB RAM on my system , Dell Latitude E4310

Comment: I can understand wanting to run a 64 bit JRE, but what is the major benefit of using a 64 bit JDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have 32bit operating system, so you cannot install 64bit application on it. Try check this by right-click on "my computer"  and choosing "properties".

I'd recommend you to try to install 32bit JDK.

Comment: I have already done that , I looked at the specs and then downloaded the JDK . It says 64 bit in system type however I have 4GB RAM .

Comment: I don't get it. Going by your comment above, why was this marked as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens more often if the downloaded file is broken. It would seem like a complete executable file, and would run properly. But, believe me, it isn't. The only remedy is to download the file once again and install.

*source: personal experience*

Comment: Even though I downloaded it from the official website ?

Comment: yeah.. sometimes it's the fault of download managers as they sometimes hang during integrity check.. and u can't see it.. it's implicit

Comment: @VarunJain do reply as soon as you solve your issue :)

Comment: I used the 32 bit version.

Comment: @VarunJain did it work?